# Macbook Air's keyboard's first row is not working when caps lock is off

Tags: keyboard, macbook, macbook-air

I have an Macbook air and something has happened today. Due to that, I can not use the first row of the keyboard(qwertyuiop) with caps lock off.
Other two rows(asdfghjkl & zxcvbnm) are working well with caps lock off. Could it be an hardware problem or a software problem?

Do you guys have any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

As the Capslock function is entirely software controlled, it cannot be a keyboard fault.

To test - System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard > Modifier Keys…

Switch the capslock key to No Action & the Fn key to Capslock. OK the dialog to set the new keys.

Test by watching the capslock light go on/off as you tap Fn.
test the upper row of keys in each case.

If it is still dependent on the capslock light, it is not a hardware fault. You will have to try track down what software may be responsible. Test another account or from safe boot.